# ConditionExpression in DynamoDB update operation gives unknown error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I'm running through a lot of items in a DynamoDB table and if the item contains a certain field (which is a object), I want to set some properties on the object on that field.

I've tried two variations of the code, but both of them give me the following unspecified error

```
{
    "errorType": "ConditionalCheckFailedException",
    "errorMessage": "The conditional request failed",
    "code": "ConditionalCheckFailedException",
    "message": "The conditional request failed",
    "time": "2020-08-29T11:44:11.703Z",
    "requestId": "IAN8A31FN2F1HR0ORT1RMTH5ENVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 26.45456917481479,
    "stack": [
        "ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed",
        "    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:51:27)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)",
        "    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)",
        "    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)",
        "    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)",
        "    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)",
        "    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)",
        "    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)"
    ]
}
```

Here's the code with named attributes

```js
          const itemParams = {
            TableName: process.env.vehiclesTableName,
            Key: { vehicleId },
            UpdateExpression:
              'set #learned.#versionId = :versionId, #learned.#fileFormat = :fileFormat',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ':versionId': VersionId,
              ':fileFormat': fileFormat,
            },
            ConditionExpression: 'attribute_exists(#learned)',
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
              '#learned': 'learned',
              '#versionId': 'versionId',
              '#fileFormat': 'fileFormat',
            },
          }
          await db.update(itemParams).promise()
```

And without named attributes

```js
          const itemParams = {
            TableName: process.env.vehiclesTableName,
            Key: { vehicleId },
            UpdateExpression:
              'set learned.versionId = :versionId, learned.fileFormat = :fileFormat',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
              ':versionId': VersionId,
              ':fileFormat': fileFormat,
            },
            ConditionExpression: 'attribute_exists(learned)',
          }
          await db.update(itemParams).promise()
```

They both behave the same.

Comment: That's no error at all, but the expected behavior when the condition isn't matched. So apparently you're trying to update an item with a "learned" attribute.

Comment: So you mean that the update function call will throw an exception (reject promise) if the condition is not met? And the error I see is that rejection?

Comment: Yes and yes. I just added an answer which also quotes the docs on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception you're seeing is actually the expected behavior and indicates that the condition didn't evaluate to true. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.MessagesAndCodes):

> **ConditionalCheckFailedException**
>
> Message: *The conditional request failed.*
>
> You specified a condition that evaluated to false. For example, you might have tried to perform a conditional update on an item, but the actual value of the attribute did not match the expected value in the condition.

As you're getting that `ConditionalCheckFailedException` exception, you're apparently trying to update an item which doesn't have a `learned` attribute.

Comment: Yes, I got it, thanks :) So I'm going to catch the exception and just move on...

I was expecting it to behave like an UPDATE ... WHERE SQL statement , fx "UPDATE table SET A = 123 WHERE B = 321"